# I need a graphical display of the influence of yearly income on the relationship of working hours and life satisfaction

Tags: r, plot, linearmodels

```
model3 <- lm(lsat ~ (wwhours + I(wwhours^2))*jahreslohn + age + I(age^2) + female + employed + log(jahreslohn) + hhsize, data = d)
```

this is my linear model. "jahreslohn" = yearly income.
i want to plot this function but I am not able to.

I tried with a new data frame keeping  all the other variables on the mean

```
# graphical display of interaction effect

newdata_inc <- data.frame( wwhours = seq(1, 70, by = 1),
                       age = mean(d$age),
                       female = "Men", "Women",
                       employed = "employed",
                       jahreslohn = d$jahreslohn,
                       hhsize = mean(d$hhsize))

newdata_inc$yhat <- predict(model3, newdata_inc)

ggplot(newdata_inc, aes(x=wwhours, y=yhat)) +
labs(x="working hours", y="Life Satisfaction") +
geom_line(aes(wwhours, yhat, linetype=jahreslohn), linewidth=1.5) +
theme_bw()   


Error in data.frame(wwhours = seq(1, 70, by = 1), age = mean(d$age), female = "Men",  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 70, 1, 188153
```